# Should a serialized Java object always be represented by the same sequence of bytes each time is it serialized?

Tags: java, serialization

For, example if the object instance was serialized (resulting in 'byte[] bs1') then serialized again (resulting in 'byte[] bs2'), should 'bs1' and 'bs2' be the same length and contain the same bytes?  If not, why not?

To avoid ambiguity, I should say that the two serializations of the same object (not two 'identical' objects - the same instance), happened within milliseconds of each other, in the same thread, on the same JVM - one before the (mutable) object was passed to a method, one after.

Note, that the object is not even being serialized, *deserialized*, and then re-serialized - it is just being serialized twice.  Also, there is nothing at all 'clever' about the object's class; it is just a simple, aggregate POJO.

I'm using the serialized bytes as an ad hoc test to detect if the object has been changed inside the method.  However, I seem to be seeing examples where the object has clearly not changed its state - yet one byte[] is different from the other.

I was assuming - and it was just an assumption - that they would be the same.  Is there some reason they might not be?

Addendum:

Also, apologies for no example code to illustrate the point.  Currently this is a small piece of code embedded in a large system.  I'll try and extract a smaller, runnable demonstration, if necessary.  I wondered if there was a basic issue with my *assumption* though, and therefore if anyone could explain why the assumption is wrong.

Comment: Proof, or it didn't happen

Comment: Why do I feel that the question does not match the title?

Comment: Of course, I suppose something *might* cause the underlying (and there, perhaps serialized form) of, for example, a collection to change, whilst the class appears unchanged (logically, it *is* unchanged) in client code.

Comment: @Wei Because if I put all the clarification in the question in the title, the title would *be* the question.  Or do I misunderstand your point?

Comment: @Paul I take it back, misunderstanding on my part (most likely, English is not my first language). FYI, the `@` did not work - you need to @Ziyao Wei.

Comment: @Ziyao Wei No problem.  Thanks for the '@' tip.

Comment: I think it should be @ZiyaoWei instead of  Ziyao<space>Wei .... no space I guess....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might not always be the *exact* same sequence of bytes that is produced through serialization. For example, the order in which a `Set` serializes its elements is not guaranteed to be constant, even if we're talking about a single instance.

Comment: Thanks.  Makes perfect sense - should have though of it whilst writing the question.  (It is a Friday!)